Pause asynchronous animation on hover
I want the animation of the hovered ball to pause, others should keep animating. Chat GPT has no clue. According to css hover should also reveal the 2nd image - > this only works when i remove javascript altogether.
Here's the codepen
const balls = document.querySelectorAll('.ball');

// Function to animate the sway of a ball
function swayBall(ball, offsetAngle) {
    const amplitude = Math.random() * 1 + 1; 
    const speed = Math.random() * 0.02 + 0.01; 

    let angle = offsetAngle; 
    let isHovered = false; 
    let animationId; // 

    function animate() {
        if (!isHovered) {
            angle += speed; 
            const swayAngle = Math.sin(angle) * amplitude; 
            ball.style.transform = `rotate(${swayAngle}deg)`; 
        }
        animationId = requestAnimationFrame(animate); 
    }

    // Start animation
    animate();

    // Stop animation on hover
    ball.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
        isHovered = true; // Stop animation
        cancelAnimationFrame(animationId); 
        ball.style.transform = ''; 
        console.log(`Hover started on:`, ball); 
    });

    // Resume animation on mouse leave
    ball.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
        isHovered = false; 
        animate(); 
        console.log(`Hover ended on:`, ball); 
    });
}

balls.forEach((ball, index) => {
    const offsetAngle = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2; 
    swayBall(ball, offsetAngle);
});

Animation works fine, but it does not stop on hover, nor does it reveal the image below.

that's happening because "hanging-balls" div has no height at all. So in reality you are not hovering to the balls. you could just give it a fixed height or 100%. I'm pretty sure that's the problem

Hi Nikoloz, thanks for answering and welcome on StackOverflow. Please consider providing your solution as code with a snippet. And maybe have a look into the guide for answers https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Your code and animation looks fine to me. But the angle is lost on hover. The reveal is working as I am seeing it. Edit: this was a test in Firefox.
I removed three lines of code and the pendulum keeps its angle.

In your "mouseenter" event listener

//cancelAnimationFrame(animationId); 
//ball.style.transform = ''; 


In your "mouseleave" event listener

//animate(); 

Edit: I changed the order of your elements to provide "correct" DOM-Order. The video is in the background, should IMHO be first. Then removed the z-index altogether, since DOM order is correct.
I gave the balls a display: inline-block; to avoid messing with static heights and fitting to content.
Changed positions to absolute to align with your video-frame.
Works for me in chrome.


const balls = document.querySelectorAll('.ball');

// Function to animate the sway of a ball
function swayBall(ball, offsetAngle) {
    const amplitude = Math.random() * 1 + 1; 
    const speed = Math.random() * 0.02 + 0.01; 

    let angle = offsetAngle; 
    let isHovered = false; 
    let animationId; // 

    function animate() {
        if (!isHovered) {
            angle += speed; 
            const swayAngle = Math.sin(angle) * amplitude; 
            ball.style.transform = `rotate(${swayAngle}deg)`; 
        }
        animationId = requestAnimationFrame(animate); 
    }

    // Start animation
    animate();

    // Stop animation on hover
    ball.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
        isHovered = true; // Stop animation
        //cancelAnimationFrame(animationId); 
        //ball.style.transform = ''; 
        console.log(`Hover started on:`, ball); 
    });

    // Resume animation on mouse leave
    ball.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
        isHovered = false; 
        //animate(); 
        console.log(`Hover ended on:`, ball); 
    });
}

balls.forEach((ball, index) => {
    const offsetAngle = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2; 
    swayBall(ball, offsetAngle);
});
.video-banner {
    width: 1600px;
    height: 600px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.video-banner video {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.hanging-balls {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: flex-start;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.ball {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 16%;
    transform-origin: top center;
    pointer-events: auto; /* Allow hover */
}

.ball img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.ball img.default {
   /* z-index: 1; *//* Default image starts on top */
}

.ball img.reveal {
    /*z-index: 2; *//* Reveal image appears above */
    opacity: 0; /* Initially invisible */
    pointer-events: none; /* Prevent interaction when not visible */
}

.ball:hover img.default {
    opacity: 0; /* Fade out the default image */
}

.ball:hover img.reveal {
    opacity: 1; /* Fade in the reveal image */
}
<div class="video-banner">
    <video autoplay muted playsinline id="banner-video" poster="https://i.ibb.co/QjnMSLG/bground.jpg" >
        <source src="https://i.ibb.co/QjnMSLG/bground.jpg" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
    <div class="hanging-balls">
        <div class="ball">
            <img class="default" src="https://i.ibb.co/ZJsMGhn/ball1.png" alt="Red Ball">
            <img class="reveal" src="https://i.ibb.co/yVBdBG1/ball1-reveal.png" alt="Red Ball Reveal">
        </div>
        <div class="ball">
            <img class="default" src="https://i.ibb.co/Hnm7NL5/ball2.png" alt="Green Ball">
            <img class="reveal" src="https://i.ibb.co/N9gmg85/ball2-reveal.png" alt="Green Ball Reveal">
        </div>
        <div class="ball">
            <img class="default" src="https://i.ibb.co/mGxgyPb/ball3.png" alt="Blue Ball">
            <img class="reveal" src=https://i.ibb.co/hDwJvbG/ball3-reveal.png" alt="Blue Ball Reveal">
        </div>
        <div class="ball">
            <img class="default" src="https://i.ibb.co/4fx06NW/ball4.png" alt="Gold Ball">
            <img class="reveal" src="https://i.ibb.co/xf5DWh0/ball4-reveal.png" alt="Gold Ball Reveal">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




Hi, i run the code you provided, ant nothing happens on hover. Animation still runs, not seeing the reveal. Tried both chrome and Edge.

Chromium seem to reduce the balls to 0, as what was said by Nikoloz Kereselidze. I changed the DOM order and removed, z-index, but most important: gave the balls a display:inline-block;
